# Import horizontal and vertical measurements into GIS

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop

I would like to import horizontal and vertical measurements into GIS. Basically, it is a recording of change in the stratigraphy of an archaeological site. I measured across the excavation from a starting point to get the horizontal measurement and then down from that point to the feature I wanted to record. Each point therefore has two measurements (horizontal and vertical). Since the recordings were recorded on a vertical wall at a site, I don't have a GPS co-ordinate for the starting point.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you want to have a map of the horizontal plane (topview) or of the vertical plane?

In case a) I suppose you have horizontal measurements with two components (x and y) plus a orientation of the x axis; and a vertical measurement with one component (z).

In case b) both measurements have one component only.

In either case, define your measurements as as CSV file example which should be easily imported into the GIS of your choice. Your coordinate system will be a local one alas just plain Cartesian coordinates. So your starting point will be (0, 0, 0) in case a) or (0, 0) in case b).

Comment: The recordings were made in a vertical wall so I want to plot that into a 2D frame. Thanks I will give this a try

Comment: If you can specify your GIS you can ask for to define a custom cartesian projection with the units your measurements are in - this would give you the benefit of having a meaningful scale.

Comment: My units are millimetres. Is it an easy process or quite complex?

Comment: What GIS are you using?

Comment: I am using QGIS but I can use ArcGIS 10 if need be

Comment: I'm always for the OSGeo way! :) Try a custom projection (Settings->Custom CRS): I used "+proj=merc +units=mm" as the definition and "Cartesian mm" as the name. You have to choose a projection (mercator in this case to have a projected one), otherwise it wouldn't work. This has no real meaning, you're only after the units=mm part.